# Can I convert hex to decimal using the calculator app?

Tags: calculator

How can we convert a hexadecimal value into  decimal by using  calculator (I know by using general formula we can do ,but is there any short key or button to do this)?

(I tried but didn't found any option )

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use Ubuntu's default calculator in programming mode.

Open the dash and search for **Calculator**, then select : **Mode** > **Programming Mode**.

[image: screenshot]

Enter the value to convert, then press **equal =**.
The entered value will get bolded. Then you may select the target Base from the drop-box to have the value converted.

Comment: This does not actually convert the number, but rather just displays it in the tool, making it impossible to use the number for further calculations.

Comment: I managed to convert, but it is in exponential notation (while preview shows it normally): 161d64aaf4d88eaa -> 1,593540529×10¹⁸ (while 1593540528574074538 is expected as shown in preview)

Answer (score 12):

And if you want something you can do from the command line, you can use trusty old `bc`

```
echo "obase=16; 255" | bc
```

produces `FF`

Answer (score 5):

When I need to convert to hex from command line, I do this:

```
printf  "%x\n" 255
```

and when I need to convert from hex, it get simpler:

```
echo $((0xff))
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't do it often but, when I do, I just use [Galculator](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/galculator/). Why do I use [Galculator](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/galculator/)? It is fast, light, and feature rich. It does everything I need it to do, these days.

If you're looking to convert then simply enter the information and then click on the appropriate button (DEC HEX OCT BIN) and it converts it for you all nice and easy like. Most of all, it's pretty small and easy to work with - I like small and simple and I also like a GUI for some things.

If you want to install it then `sudo apt-get install galculator` and follow the prompts.

Comment: I do not like it at all. You don't get instant representation of hex,bin values like `Calculator` in accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

> **`dc(1)`**

**D**esktop **C**alculator, absolutely:

```
> dc <<< '16i FF p'
255
```

- `16i` is for input base16
- `p` for *print*

PS Other useful conversions:

```
> dc <<< '16o 255 p'   # decimal2hex
FF
> dc <<< '2o 16i EF p' # hex2binary
11101111
> dc <<< '2o 7 p'      # decimal2binary
111
```

@see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/calculate-dc